# How to make multiple paths to an IF statement Google Apps Script/Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am trying to run an onEdit command for several different things, since it isn't possible to run 2 simultaneously, I have combined them into a single `if` statement. This is through a google sheet I am coding.

The check box is in "Waitlist" and the sent data is to "archive".

Check box is selected
Multiple paths exist;

[1] if box is checked in row 3 through to ~17 (it just has to 10atm)
copy row to a different sheet called archives, delete the row then create a new blank row.

[2] if box is checked in row 31 onwards, copy then move data to same archive, then delete row.

The code I have:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;

    if (src.getName() != "Waitlist" || r.columnStart != 11 || r.rowStart !==4 && r.rowStart !==5 && r.rowStart !==6 && r.rowStart !==7 && r.rowStart !==8 && r.rowStart !==9 && r.rowStart !==10 ) 
    return; 
// does it meet criteria [1]? 
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var range = ss.getRange("Waitlist!B18:L18");
      var row = range.getRowIndex();
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(17, 1);
      range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1, 1, column), {contentsOnly:false});
// create copy of row with drop downs.
      
      const dest2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Archives");
      src.getRange(r.rowStart,3,1,10).moveTo(dest2.getRange(dest2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,10));
      src.deleteRow(r.rowStart)
// move then delete row.

      
    if (src.getName() != "Waitlist" || r.columnStart != 11 || r.rowStart != 31 && r.rowStart !=32 && r.rowStart !=33 && r.rowStart !=34) 
    return;
// does it meet criteria [2]?
      const dest1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Archives");
      src.getRange(r.rowStart,3,1,10).moveTo(dest1.getRange(dest1.getLastRow()+1,1,1,10));
      src.deleteRow(r.rowStart)
//move then delete row.
}
```

The issue is, when I execute it, it will only do one of the two paths.
I am not sure what I am missing here...

Comment: that's a lot of || and && - are you sure the boolean logic of those OR's and AND's is correct - Boolean logic can be tricky

Comment: `it will only do one of the two paths.` which path is taken and what are the relevant values?

Comment: You can several different operations in the same onEdit function.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I got it working, found the triggers section, and separated them into 3 separate functions.

Now it works for all 3 different sections I needed it to.

It now creates a new row with the required variables, while also moving the row that has been checked.

Thank you to everyone who replied!

```
// Standard Grinding Archive
function onEdit1(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const x = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "Grinding Waitlist" || x.columnStart != 13 || x.rowStart !=5 && x.rowStart != 6 && x.rowStart != 7 && x.rowStart != 8) return;
  const dest1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Grinding Archives");
  src.getRange(x.rowStart,4,1,9).moveTo(dest1.getRange(dest1.getLastRow()+1,2,1,8));
  src.deleteRow(x.rowStart);


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange("Grinding Waitlist!B20:M20");
  var row = range.getRowIndex();

 sheet.insertRowsAfter(19, 1);
 range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1, 1, column), {contentsOnly:false});
  
}
// Fest Grinding Archive
function onEdit3(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const x = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "Grinding Waitlist" || x.columnStart != 13 || x.rowStart !=27 && x.rowStart != 28 && x.rowStart != 29 && x.rowStart != 30) return;
  const dest1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Grinding Archives");
  src.getRange(x.rowStart,4,1,9).moveTo(dest1.getRange(dest1.getLastRow()+1,2,1,8));
  src.deleteRow(x.rowStart);
} 

// Leveling Archive 
function onEdit2(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if(src.getName() != "Leveling Waitlist" ||  r.rowStart == 1 || r.columnStart != 12 ) return;
  const dest2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Leveling Archives");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,4,1,8).moveTo(dest2.getRange(dest2.getLastRow()+1,2,1,6));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart); 

  // code for making a new row. 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange("Leveling Waitlist!B20:M20");
  var row = range.getRowIndex();

  sheet.insertRowsAfter(19, 1);
  range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1, 1, column), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```